# Jetty Webservice - https protocol based address is not supported

Tags: web-services, ssl, jetty

I am using jetty version 7.5.1 .

My webservice works fine with a "http://..." endpoint, but when I change it to "http**s**://..." things go wrong.

```
Endpoint e = Endpoint.create(webservice);
e.publish("https://localhost:" +  serverPort + "/ws/mywebservice);
```

I get the following error message:
*"https protocol based address is not supported".*

I've tried using an `SslChannelConnector`, a `SelectChannelConnector` and the combination of both.

```
  Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
  connector.setPort(59180);

  SslContextFactory factory = new SslContextFactory();
  factory.setKeyStore("keystore");
  factory.setKeyStorePassword("password");
  factory.setKeyManagerPassword("password");
  factory.setTrustStore("keystore");
  factory.setTrustStorePassword("password");

  SslSelectChannelConnector sslConnector = new SslSelectChannelConnector(factory);
  sslConnector.setPort(443);
  sslConnector.setMaxIdleTime(30000);

  server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector, sslConnector});
```

I also tried modifying the port in the publish path. But without success.

Could it be that something went wrong with the creation of my keystore file?
Even I put the wrong password though, it does show a different error message, explaining that my password is wrong.

My options are running out. Any ideas?

## EDIT: More information:

**Servlets work fine with HTTPS now.** But the **webservices are not.** Am I maybe publishing it the wrong way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several threads on various forums with similar problems. But never found a solution. I would like to write down my solution for future victims:

The `publish` method **only accepts the http protocol**. Even if you are publishing for https, this should still be `"http://..."`. On the other hand, you should **use the port of your SSL connector**.

```
Endpoint e = Endpoint.create(webservice);
e.publish("http://localhost:443/ws/mywebservice);
```

Use any other protocol and you will always get the *"xxx protocol based address is not supported"* exception. [See source code.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/transport/http/server/EndpointImpl.java#134)

**Note 1:** The webservice already works fine at this point. However there is a point of discussion: The generated wsdl file (at `https://localhost:443/ws/mywebservice?wsdl`) will reference the `http://...` path. You could argue if the wsdl file is a requirement or just documentation.

Correcting a hostname in a WSDL file is not that hard, but replacing the protocol is harder. The easiest solution is probably to **just edit the wsdl file and host the file**, which is not very "dynamic" of course.

Alternatively, **I solved it by creating a WsdlServlet** which replaces the address. On the other hand, it does feel bad to create an entire class just to fix 1 character. :)

**Note 2:** Another bug in this jetty release, is the authentication. It's impossible to offer the webservice without any authentication. The best thing you can get, after turning off all possible authentication: you will still have to use 'preemptive authentication' and enter a random username and password.