# https protocol based address is not supported - javax.xml.ws.Endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, https

I'm trying to create a web service independent or Tomcat of any other Application Server, works well with http, but with https I get the error below. Seems all the documentation relates either to a client example or application server example.
A link to a good tutorial would be great.

Thanks!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: https protocol based address is not supported   
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:149)           
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:107)            

     at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:181)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used something like

```
Endpoint.publish("https://localhost:9999/abc", new YourEndpoint());
```

to publish your web service endpoint, and got specified exception - looks like internal JDK web server does not support HTTPS.

Please refer here for more information: [JAX-WS2 and HTTPS](http://www.coderanch.com/t/225520/Web-Services/java/JAX-WS-HTTPS).
And this page has Jetty related information, but it is useful as well: [Jetty Webservice - https protocol based address is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437986/jetty-webservice-https-protocol-based-address-is-not-supported).

If you don't want to mess with "heavy" Tomcat server, you can use something lightweight.
These pages have good examples of doing it: [Java Webservice using HTTPS part 1](http://www.sothawo.com/2011/10/java-webservice-using-https/) and [How to develop a standalone SSL web service](https://alesaudate.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/how-to-develop-a-standalone-ssl-web-service/).

It does not answer question to not use any application server at all, but hope it helps.